# App flutter não consegue conectar com API em dispositivo fisico

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, flutter, app

Tenho tido problemas com o **flutter** na hora de testar minha aplicação em um dispositivo físico, pois no emulador ele funciona perfeitamente, no físico a API é como se não se conectasse com meu dispositivo, estão conectados na mesma rede, inclusive conectei no mesmo roteador para ter mais certeza, mas ele não consegue conectar-se ao servidor API. O dispositivo é um samsung **Tab S5**. Se eu subir o app no emulador funciona perfeitamente com a API, mas no físico não. Minha API está em **Ruby on Rails**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se as portas estão abertas para conexões externas.

Desative brevemente o firewall para testar.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: NOOOSSA funcionou tranquilo ksksk não tinha pensado nisso kskks muito obrigado

Comment: Muito de nada. Que bom que ajudei.